# OUI JD Edwards EnterpiriseOne Standalone Installation

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, jdedwards

I am trying to install JDE EnterpiriseOne on a virtual machine running win7, i followed the instructions in this video :
[JDE 9.1 stanalone instalation toturial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viVv8czK2EM)

I installed "EnterpiriseOne Database Engine" of course after installing oracle client, but i cannot continue to install the "EnterpiriseOne E910 Standalone client"...

it seems to be a problem with the oracle universal Universal installer finding a running Database, i checked the listener services and found that they are running...

typed the command (`lsnrctl status`) in cmd, and got the following:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-JUL-2013 18:38
:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.119.128)(PORT=15
21)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out
   64-bit Windows Error: 60: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                27-JUL-2013 17:14:33
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 24 min. 1 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   c:\Oracle\E1Local\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\WIN-I3MMKFMQE20\listener\alert\
log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.119.128)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

PLZ anyone what can i do to complete the instalation???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your tnsnames.ora and listener.ora try to change the *HOST* value for 127.0.0.1. Then restart the database and the listener services.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 127.0.0.1 change it to hostname. It worked fine for me after changing this to hostname.